# Winforms - how to create something similar to a master page?

Tags: winforms, menu, master-pages, panel

I'm trying to build an app in winforms with something similiar to masterpages in asp.net - a menu on top and when choosing an option from the menu the entire screen on the bottom will change while the menu remains (there are 10-15 screens in the future app, some are quite similar, some are not).

What is the best way of doing this? Should I use different forms for each screen or use a panel or something else?

If I use a panel or something how do I manage to use the designer with so many panels taking space on the screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is just keeping the same menu and opening/closing parts of the UI you could simply add and remove instances of usercontrols to the main form.

If you need more features such as docking (like Visual Studio) [look at this](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dockpanelsuite/)

Another option is to [use Form inheritance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983613%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Which one to select depends on what you want to reuse and the features you need.

Comment: Thank you, you saved my life. I followed this [link](http://www.dountsis.com/articles/dot-net/how-to-use-user-controls-to-create-mdi-winform-applications.php) to see a demo of changing UIs (just had to tweak few lines to make it work - replaced `controlName = c.GetType().ToString();` with `controlName = c.GetType().Name;` added in the ctor `ucForm1.Visible = false; this.Controls.Add(ucForm1);` and deleted the line `c.Dock = DockStyle.None;` to prevent a blinking bug

Answer (score 1):

Try with the MDIParent Form's. View the Example 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12514/Multi-Document-Interface-MDI-tab-page-browsing-wit

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to make your application an MDI window and then load entire forms, maximized, into the parent window.

Then, you would be able to treat each form as its own self-contained item, since it really would be exactly that.

Is it not an option for you to use WPF?  A WPF browser application fits the paradigm you are describing quite well.